# Javascript regex: check if a string is alphanumeric AND it contains a letter (at least)

Tags: javascript, regex

The string length can be 4 - 12 characters.
It may contain **ONLY letters and numbers**, but it has to contain **at least 1 number**.

And I need to solve this with a single regex pattern.

I tried something like:

```
 /^(?=.*[a-z]*)(?=.*[0-9]+).{4,12}$/i
```

This won't accept less than 4 or more than 12 chars and it also checks if the string contains a number, but obviously it's not good because of the .* parts. 
I wasn't able to figure out how to exclude all non-alphanumeric characters.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your pattern is close, but I would use this:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{4,12}$/i
```

The only lookahead you need is one which asserts that there is a single number.  There is no requirement for there to be any letters, so don't bother adding an assertion for that.  Then, match any alphanumeric character 4 to 12 times.

```js
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{4,12}$/i.test('abc'));
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{4,12}$/i.test('123'));
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{4,12}$/i.test('abcd'));
console.log(/^(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{4,12}$/i.test('Abc1'));
```

Comment: Is the `i` flag really necessary since you're including `A-Z`? I think you should be able to simplify be removing any of them.